# C Strtok Segfaulting

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm not sure why the following code is segfaulting:

```
char * buffer = "SIZE";
char * tempString;
tempString = strtok(buffer, " ");
if(strcmp(tempString, "SIZE") == 0){    
    tempString = strtok(NULL, " ");           <----Faulting here
}
```

Since there is nothing left to tokenate shouldn't tempString just be equal to NULL? Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go over the tokenized elements as [the reference says](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), you have a clean approach if you follow it.

CORRECT CODE:

```
char buffer[] = "SIZE";
char * tok;
tok = strtok(buffer, " ");
while(tok != NULL)
{
  if(strcmp(tok, "SIZE") != 0)    
    break;
  tok = strtok(NULL, " ");        //   <----Faulted here
}
```

yes, it may skip multiple "SIZE" words in the buffer, so it does a bit more than what you originally did, but it is easier to read for an other programmer (and easier to recall it later, for you too).

Comment: Change `char * buffer = "SIZE";` to `char buffer[] = "SIZE";`. Passing a string literal to `strtok` is wrong.

Comment: This solution seemed to work best in my situation, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

There are two problems:

First, `strtok` requires a modifiable string for the first parameter and `buffer` in your example is not.  Try this instead:

```
char buffer[] = "SIZE";
```

Second, `strcmp` doesn't handle `NULL` which `strtok` can return:

```
if (NULL != tempString && strcmp(tempString, "SIZE") == 0)
```

Comment: Just run the OP program with the change you suggested and the segmentation fault still appears.

Comment: @HernanVelasquez Then your C library must be buggy. `strtok(buffer," ")` must return `&buffer[0]` there, the following `strtok(NULL; " ")` must return `NULL`.

Comment: @DanielFischer  It's possible.  I just run the OP's program again including the string.h and worked perfectly, even with the char * buffer = "SIZE"; declaration.

Comment: @HernanVelasquez Was the crash without including `string.h`? Then the code crashing would be expected on a 64-bit system (without prototype, `strtok` would have been assumed to return `int` in C89/C90, so the returned pointer would have been converted to `int` in between and thus `tempString` would have gotten garbage; implicit function declarations are still accepted by default with many compilers, even though they have been removed already in C99). That it didn't crash with `char *buffer = "SIZE";` is surprising, but allowed, modifying string literals is UB, need not crash.

Comment: @DanielFischer Great post, and yes if I compile to program without the string.h header, I got this warning:  test.c:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast justifying your argument.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have been including string.h the entire time. The suggestions given by IronMensan have stopped the code from segfaulting, however, the program still moves into the if statement despite after calling strtok on buffer there should be nothing left to tokenate.

Comment: @NightTrain Yes, the `strtok(buffer, " ")` just overwrites the terminating 0-byte with a 0, so the contents of `buffer` didn't change,and the `strcmp` returns 0, since both strings are equal. Thus you enter the `if` and call `strtok(NULL, " ")`. Since there is no `' '` in the string, that call returns `NULL`.